# Karlin-Rubin's theorem in the setting of the uniform distribution

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, inference, frequentist, point-estimation

Suppose that I have a population desribed by $X\sim U(0,\theta)$, where $\theta$ is unknown. I want to test $$\begin{cases} H_0:\,\theta\leq 30 \\ H_A:\,\theta>30\end{cases}$$ using the uniformly most powerful test. By the form of the test, I thought of using Karlin-Rubin's Theorem.

First, one checks that the likelihood ratio is nondecreasing with respect to $\max\{x_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$. Then, by Karlin-Rubin, the critical region is of the form $$\text{CR}=\{\vec{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n):\,\max_{1\leq i\leq n}x_i\geq c\},$$ where $c$ is chosen so that the test has size $\alpha$: $$\alpha=\sup_{\theta\leq 30}P(\text{CR}|\theta)=P(\text{CR}|\theta=30).$$
Put for instance $\alpha=0.05$ and $n=30$. If one computes $$0.05=P(CR|\theta=30)=\int_c^{30} f_{\max_{1\leq i\leq 30}X_i} (x)\,dx\stackrel{\substack{\text{compute} \\ \text{density} \\ \text{of max}}}{=}\int_c^{30}30\frac{x^{29}}{30^{30}}\,dx=1-\frac{c^{30}}{30^{30}},$$so $c\approx 29.95$, but this does not make sense: if I obtain in a sample of size $30$ a maximum value of, say, $29.98$, from this $\text{CR}$ I should reject $H_0$, but my sample goes "in the direction" of $H_0$. What happens?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this result "does not make sense"?  When the largest of $n$ values gets anywhere close to $30$, one would suspect that $\theta$ likely exceeds $30$.  By the time the maximum actually equals or exceeds $30$, you can be *certain* the null is false.

Comment: @whuber Usually, when the maximum likelihood estimator (in this case $\max_{1\leq i\leq 30}x_i$) satisfies what the null hypothesis states ($\theta\leq 30$), you don't have evidence against $H_0$, so you accept it, and not reject it as it happens in this example. For example, if you perform a likelihood ratio test, the critical region is $\{\vec{x}:\,\Delta(\vec{x})\leq k\}$, where $$\Delta(\vec{x})=\frac{\sup_{\theta\leq 30}L(\theta|\vec{x})}{L(\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}|\vec{x})},\;\;\hat{\theta}_{\text{MLE}}=\max_{1\leq i\leq 30}x_i.$$

Comment: Continuation: If $\max_{1\leq i\leq 30}x_i\leq 30$ (your sample goes "in the direction " of $H_0$), then $\Delta(\vec{x})=1$, and $H_0$ is accepted. If $\max_{1\leq i\leq 30}x_i>30$, it can be seen that $H_0$ is rejected for any size $\alpha$ of the test. For me, it's strange that Karlin-Rubin and LRT do not give rise to the same conclusion.

Comment: Your "usually" appears to ignore the entire idea of a likelihood *ratio*.  Any maxima close to $30$, but slightly less than that, clearly constitute evidence *against* $H_0$ because they are more likely under some alternatives with $\theta\gt 30$ than they are under $H_0$.

Comment: @whuber So Karlin-Rubin and the LRT do not coincide in this case?

Comment: I mis-stated something in the preceding comment: the LR for a maximum less than $30$ will be constantly $1$. The point is that for a hypothesis test of size $\alpha$--this may sound strange--you *must* reject the hypothesis with a probability of $100\alpha\%$ when $H_0$ holds. If you don't do this and insist you will accept $H_0$ whenever the statistic is less than $30$, you will have no power to reject the hypothesis when $H_A$ just "barely" holds (ie., when $\theta$ exceeds $30$ but is close to it). The question devolves to finding which subset of $[0,30]$ should lie in the rejection region.